Not able to run spyder after installing both opencv and alphashape
Installing both alphashape and opencv seems to create problems that prevents running spyder.
Case that does not work in the sense that I can not run spyder:
conda env remove -n myenv_1 -y && conda create -n myenv_1 python=3.10.14 -y && conda activate myenv_1 && conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y && conda install numpy matplotlib pandas -y && conda install spyder -y && conda install -c anaconda scipy -y && conda install scikit-learn numba -y && conda install plotly -y && conda install openpyxl -y && conda install -c conda-forge alphashape -y && conda install -c conda-forge opencv -y

Then conda list returns:
# packages in environment at C:\Users\BrianB\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.16          py310haa95532_0
alphashape                1.3.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
....
freeglut                  3.2.2                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
freexl                    2.0.0                h8276f4a_0    conda-forge
gdal                      3.6.2           py310h7670e6c_4
geopandas                 0.14.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopandas-base            0.14.4             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.8.0                he025d50_1    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.7.0                h4545760_3
gettext                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
gettext-tools             0.22.5               h7d00a51_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.78.4               hd77b12b_0
glib-tools                2.78.4               hd77b12b_0
graphite2                 1.3.13            h63175ca_1003    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.22.9               h001b923_1    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.22.9               hb4038d2_1    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  6.0.0                he256f1b_0    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            h0e5069d_1005    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.1               h51c971a_3
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2    anaconda
icu                       70.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.7             py310haa95532_0
imagesize                 1.4.1           py310haa95532_0
importlib-metadata        7.0.1           py310haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1           py310haa95532_0
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46320
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.28.0          py310haa95532_0
ipython                   8.20.0          py310haa95532_0
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jaraco.classes            3.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jasper                    2.0.33               hc2e4405_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1          py310haa95532_1
jellyfish                 1.0.1           py310h36a85e1_0
jinja2                    3.1.4           py310haa95532_0
joblib                    1.4.2           py310haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonschema                4.19.2          py310haa95532_0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1        py310haa95532_0
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.5.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2           py310haa95532_0
kealib                    1.5.0                hde4a422_1
keyring                   24.3.1          py310haa95532_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h5b6d351_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.10.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libasprintf               0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libasprintf-devel         0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           1_h8933c1f_netlib    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libcblas                  3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
libclang                  15.0.7          default_h77d9078_3    conda-forge
libclang13                15.0.7          default_h77d9078_3    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.7.1                h86230a5_0
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_1
libexpat                  2.6.2                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_1
libgdal                   3.6.2                h9a21643_4
libgettextpo              0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libgettextpo-devel        0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libglib                   2.78.4               ha17d25a_0
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
libintl                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libintl-devel             0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h9859afa_1014    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.8.1                h6685c40_4
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libopencv                 4.7.0           py310h90026ac_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libpq                     12.17                h906ac69_0
libprotobuf               3.21.12              h12be248_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libspatialite             5.1.0                hbdd3232_0
libsqlite                 3.46.0               h2466b09_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               h9a1e1f7_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                hd77b12b_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.10.4               h0ad7f3c_2
libzip                    1.8.0                h519de47_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h2466b09_6    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.42.0          py310hf2fb9eb_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_1
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
mapclassify               2.6.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            2.2.0           py310haa95532_1
markupsafe                2.1.3           py310h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.8.4           py310haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.8.4           py310h4ed8f06_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310haa95532_0
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mdurl                     0.1.0           py310haa95532_0
minizip                   4.0.3                hb68bac4_0
mistune                   2.0.4           py310haa95532_0
mkl                       2023.1.0         h6b88ed4_46358
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py310h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py310h59b6b97_0
more-itertools            10.1.0          py310haa95532_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
munch                     4.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mypy_extensions           1.0.0           py310haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.8.0           py310haa95532_0
nbconvert                 7.10.0          py310haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.9.2           py310haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py310haa95532_0
networkx                  3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
numba                     0.59.1          py310hd77b12b_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310h2cd9be0_0
numpy                     1.26.4          py310h055cbcc_0
numpy-base                1.26.4          py310h65a83cf_0
numpydoc                  1.5.0           py310haa95532_0
opencv                    4.7.0           py310h5588dad_1    conda-forge
openh264                  2.3.1                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl                  3.1.2           py310h2bbff1b_0
openssl                   3.3.1                h2466b09_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2            py310haa95532_0
pandas                    2.2.1           py310h5da7b33_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathspec                  0.10.3          py310haa95532_0
pcre2                     10.42                h0ff8eda_1
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    10.3.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pip                       24.0            py310haa95532_0
pixman                    0.43.4               h63175ca_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310haa95532_0
plotly                    5.22.0          py310h9909e9c_0
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310haa95532_1
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
poppler                   22.12.0              h0bf3bde_3
poppler-data              0.4.12               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
proj                      9.3.1                ha107b6e_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py310haa95532_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-opencv                 4.7.0           py310hbbfc1a7_1    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.11.1          py310haa95532_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.3.0           py310haa95532_0
pyflakes                  3.2.0           py310haa95532_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py310haa95532_1
pylint                    2.16.2          py310haa95532_0
pylint-venv               3.0.3           py310haa95532_0
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl                    1.5.0           py310h8cc25b3_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310haa95532_0
pyproj                    3.6.1           py310h05d47c7_5    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py310h2bbff1b_0
pyqtwebengine             5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
python                    3.10.14              he1021f5_1
python-dateutil           2.9.0post0      py310haa95532_2
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py310haa95532_0
python-lsp-black          2.0.0           py310haa95532_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.10.0          py310haa95532_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytoolconfig              1.2.6           py310haa95532_0
pytz                      2024.1          py310haa95532_0
....

Error when opening spyder:
(myenv_1) C:\Users\...>spyder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 36, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 287, in <module>
    raise QtBindingsNotFoundError from None
qtpy.QtBindingsNotFoundError: No Qt bindings could be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 252, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 41, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 48, in check_qt
    show_warning("Failed to import qtpy.\n"
  File "C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\myenv_1\lib\site-packages\spyder\requirements.py", line 29, in show_warning
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Failed to import qtpy.
Please check Spyder installation requirements:

qtpy 1.2.0+ and
PyQt5 5.10+

are required to run Spyder.

removing and reinstalling qtpy, PyQt5 and/spyder does not fix this.
Case where I do not install alphashape that works in the sense that I can run spyder (it also works if I install alphashape but not opencv):
conda env remove -n myenv_1 -y && conda create -n myenv_1 python=3.10.14 -y && conda activate myenv_1 && conda update -n base -c defaults conda -y && conda install numpy matplotlib pandas -y && conda install spyder -y && conda install -c anaconda scipy -y && conda install scikit-learn numba -y && conda install plotly -y && conda install openpyxl -y && conda install -c conda-forge opencv -y

Then conda list returns:
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.16          py310haa95532_0
aom                       3.6.1                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
arrow                     1.2.3           py310haa95532_1
astroid                   2.14.2          py310haa95532_0
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     23.1.0          py310haa95532_0
autopep8                  2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.11.0          py310haa95532_0
bcrypt                    3.2.0           py310h2bbff1b_1
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3          py310haa95532_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     24.4.2          py310haa95532_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck                1.3.7           py310h9128911_0
brotli                    1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
brotli-python             1.0.9           py310hd77b12b_8
bzip2                     1.0.8                h2bbff1b_6
ca-certificates           2024.6.2             h56e8100_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            hd694305_1014    conda-forge
certifi                   2024.6.2           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.16.0          py310h2bbff1b_1
chardet                   4.0.0           py310haa95532_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     8.1.7           py310haa95532_0
cloudpickle               2.2.1           py310haa95532_0
colorama                  0.4.6           py310haa95532_0
comm                      0.2.1           py310haa95532_0
contourpy                 1.2.0           py310h59b6b97_0
cookiecutter              2.6.0           py310haa95532_0
cryptography              42.0.5          py310h89fc84f_1
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
dav1d                     1.2.1                hcfcfb64_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7           py310hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.8           py310haa95532_0
docstring-to-markdown     0.11            py310haa95532_0
docutils                  0.18.1          py310haa95532_3
et_xmlfile                1.1.0           py310haa95532_0
exceptiongroup            1.2.0           py310haa95532_0
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
expat                     2.6.2                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    5.1.2           gpl_h8bb4bc8_112    conda-forge
flake8                    7.0.0           py310haa95532_0
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 h77eed37_2    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               hbde0cde_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.51.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
freeglut                  3.2.2                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               ha860e81_0
gettext                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
gettext-tools             0.22.5               h7d00a51_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.80.2               h0df6a38_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.80.2               h2f9d560_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h63175ca_1003    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.22.9               h001b923_1    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.22.9               hb4038d2_1    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  6.0.0                he256f1b_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2022.1.0             h6049295_2    anaconda
icu                       70.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.7             py310haa95532_0
imagesize                 1.4.1           py310haa95532_0
importlib-metadata        7.0.1           py310haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1           py310haa95532_0
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         h59b6b97_46320
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.28.0          py310haa95532_0
ipython                   8.20.0          py310haa95532_0
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jaraco.classes            3.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jasper                    2.0.33               hc2e4405_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1          py310haa95532_1
jellyfish                 1.0.1           py310h36a85e1_0
jinja2                    3.1.4           py310haa95532_0
joblib                    1.4.2           py310haa95532_0
jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_1
jsonschema                4.19.2          py310haa95532_0
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1        py310haa95532_0
jupyter_client            8.6.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyter_core              5.5.0           py310haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.2.2           py310haa95532_0
keyring                   24.3.1          py310haa95532_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310hd77b12b_0
krb5                      1.20.1               h5b6d351_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.10.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0
lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0
libasprintf               0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libasprintf-devel         0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           1_h8933c1f_netlib    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h2bbff1b_8
libcblas                  3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
libclang                  15.0.7          default_h3a3e6c3_5    conda-forge
libclang13                15.0.7          default_hf64faad_5    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.17                 h2bbff1b_1
libexpat                  2.6.2                h63175ca_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                hd77b12b_1
libgettextpo              0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libgettextpo-devel        0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libglib                   2.80.2               h0df6a38_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hcfcfb64_2    conda-forge
libintl                   0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
libintl-devel             0.22.5               h5728263_2    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0           5_hd5c7e75_netlib    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libopencv                 4.7.0           py310h90026ac_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               h8cc25b3_0
libpq                     12.17                h906ac69_0
libprotobuf               3.21.12              h12be248_2    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h62dcd97_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0
libsqlite                 3.46.0               h2466b09_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.5.1                hd77b12b_0
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.12.7               h283a6d9_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h2466b09_6    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.42.0          py310hf2fb9eb_0
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h2bbff1b_1
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    conda-forge
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    conda-forge
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            2.2.0           py310haa95532_1
markupsafe                2.1.3           py310h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.8.4           py310haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.8.4           py310h4ed8f06_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py310haa95532_0
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
mdurl                     0.1.0           py310haa95532_0
mistune                   2.0.4           py310haa95532_0
mkl                       2023.1.0         h6b88ed4_46358
mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py310h2bbff1b_0
mkl_random                1.2.4           py310h59b6b97_0
more-itertools            10.1.0          py310haa95532_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    conda-forge
mypy_extensions           1.0.0           py310haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.8.0           py310haa95532_0
nbconvert                 7.10.0          py310haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.9.2           py310haa95532_0
nest-asyncio              1.6.0           py310haa95532_0
numba                     0.59.1          py310hd77b12b_0
numexpr                   2.8.7           py310h2cd9be0_0
numpy                     1.26.4          py310h055cbcc_0
numpy-base                1.26.4          py310h65a83cf_0
numpydoc                  1.5.0           py310haa95532_0
opencv                    4.7.0           py310h5588dad_1    conda-forge
openh264                  2.3.1                h63175ca_2    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0
openpyxl                  3.1.2           py310h2bbff1b_0
openssl                   3.3.1                h2466b09_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2            py310haa95532_0
pandas                    2.2.1           py310h5da7b33_0
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathspec                  0.10.3          py310haa95532_0
pcre2                     10.43                h17e33f8_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    10.3.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
pip                       24.0            py310haa95532_0
pixman                    0.43.4               h63175ca_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0          py310haa95532_0
plotly                    5.22.0          py310h9909e9c_0
pluggy                    1.0.0           py310haa95532_1
ply                       3.11            py310haa95532_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.43          py310haa95532_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.43               hd3eb1b0_0
psutil                    5.9.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
py-opencv                 4.7.0           py310hbbfc1a7_1    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.11.1          py310haa95532_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.3.0           py310haa95532_0
pyflakes                  3.2.0           py310haa95532_0
pygments                  2.15.1          py310haa95532_1
pylint                    2.16.2          py310haa95532_0
pylint-venv               3.0.3           py310haa95532_0
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pynacl                    1.5.0           py310h8cc25b3_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py310haa95532_0
pyqt                      5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pyqt5-sip                 12.13.0         py310h2bbff1b_0
pyqtwebengine             5.15.10         py310hd77b12b_0
pysocks                   1.7.1           py310haa95532_0
python                    3.10.14              he1021f5_1
...

I have tried this for python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10.14, and 3.11.9  with the same result
I tried installing modules in different order and I have tried this for python 3.8, 3.9, 3.10.14, and 3.11.9 with the same result. I have tried this on windows 10 and 11.
